# Constructors calling other constructors in vb.net a la c#

Tags: vb.net

In c# you can have

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(string name)
    {
        //do something
    }

    public Foo(string name, int bar) : this(name)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Is there a VB.Net equivalent?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

It looks similar to Java in this respect:

```
Public Class Foo
    Public Sub New(name As String)
        ' Do something '
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(name As String, bar As Integer)
        Me.New(name)
        ' Do something '
    End Sub
End Class
```

Note that you have to use `MyBase.New(...)` in case you want to call a constructor of a base class. See also [VB.NET OOP Part2 – Understanding Constructors](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/11/04/vbooppt2.htm?page=1).

Comment: Thanks. I thought it might be something like that but I was putting Me(name) rather than Me.New

Comment: One more note. It has to be the first line!

Comment: One more other note: if you want to set non-constructor properties inline, like in c#, you can type: Dim foo As New Foo("someName","someBar") With {.SomeOtherProperty = False, .IsDirty=False }